# MinGW g++ 4.8.1-4 doesn't recognize -std=c++14

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, mingw, c++14

I installed MinGW by following their [home page](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MinGW) to their [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/?source=navbar) and using mingw-get-setup.exe. This installed g++ 4.8.1-4. GCC 4.8 is [supposed to](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html) support C++14 with a command-line switch, but I just get an "unrecognized option" error.

Is this a bug with MinGW? With GCC? What can I do about it? <del>Since I know someone will ask, I want C++14 for its for-each loops. I'm using iterators for now, but for-each would improve both readability and writability.</del>

EDIT: Found out my g++ build supports c++11, so I can use for-each. But still no luck on c++14 support.

Comment: I doubt that it is a bug...

Comment: What's a "C++14 for-each loop"?

Comment: Lets you iterate over `vector<Thing>` with `for (Thing t : things)`

Comment: If all you want is the new `for`-std=c++11 should get it done.

Comment: You're right, thanks. But the unrecognized option error still isn't resolved, so I'm keeping the question up.

Comment: Try adding -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ as well. Smurfed if I know what's experimental about C++11 at this point, though.

Comment: @LastStar007 the term you're looking for is a *range-based for loop*.  Since C++ doesn't have a *for-each loop*, it's hazardous for us to guess what that means.  We're sometimes awful guessers.  Good luck!

Comment: @DrewDormann Why split hairs? I'm talking about a feature colloquially called for-each in a variety of languages, that was added in C++11, with a syntax example, and emphatically not spelled `std::for_each`. How much clearer can you get?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

g++ 4.8 simply does not support C++14, also MinGW is quite outdated when there are more new versions of gcc.

## Alternatives you can use

If you want really to use C++11 or C++14 on windows with gcc you should be using one of the following options:

- https://msys2.github.io/ (Uses MinGW-w64 internally).
- http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php (it supports 32-bits too).
- http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/.